# Error: No native splash screen registered for given view controller. for react-native expo using expo-splash-screen

Tags: react-native, expo

`Unhandled promise rejection: Error: No native splash screen registered for given view controller. Call 'SplashScreen.show' for given view controller first.`

I get the following warning only on my ios emulator when I first launch the app. Not on my ios physical device or android emulator. I am using `expo-splash-screen` for my splash screen. Is this something I can just ignore or do I need to resolve it because I can't figure out how to resolve it. The splash screen seems to load fine. Is it an error with `expo-splash-screen`? I followed [expo's tutorial](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/) on setting it up.

**warning:**

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: No native splash screen registered for given view controller. Call 'SplashScreen.show' for given view controller first.]
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:103:50 in promiseMethodWrapper
at node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/build/NativeModulesProxy.native.js:15:23 in moduleName.methodInfo.name
at node_modules/expo-splash-screen/build/SplashScreen.js:23:17 in hideAsync
at node_modules/expo-splash-screen/build/SplashScreen.js:19:7 in hideAsync
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

**index.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

import Navigation from './config/Navigation';

export default function App() {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        // keep splash screen visible while we fetch resources
        await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
        // Pre-load fonts, make any api calls here
        await Asset.loadAsync(require('../assets/IMG_0024.jpg'));
        // Artificially delay for two seconds to simulate a slow loading
        // experience. Please remove this if you copy and paste the code!
        // await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        // Tell app to render
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      // This tells the splash screen to hide immediately! If we call this after
      // `setAppIsReady`, then we may see a blank screen while the app is
      // loading its initial state and rendering its first pixels. So instead,
      // we hide the splash screen once we know the root view has already
      // performed layout.
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  onLayoutRootView();

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }

  return <Navigation />;
}
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "name",
    "slug": "slug",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#fffffb"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["assets/images/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFB"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @barods did this got resolved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is caused because u're using `AppLoading`, this component is currently having this bug on iOS.

You can solve this avoid using this component until the bug is resolved, an alternative is create a Screen like your Splashscreen and replace `<AppLoading />` to `<MyAwesomeSplashScreen />`

... or in a ruder and lazy way **(bad UX)** just change `<AppLoading />` to `<View />`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you. OP needs to make this the answer.

Comment: Solve it using which component??

Comment: @kd12345 I solved this creating a JSX component with UX that I want on app Splash Screen

Comment: Its working on ios but not on android

Comment: I'm not using AppLoader, yet still see this

Comment: @HungVu same here... this was working fine until I started playing with Redux.  Now I have "undo"ed all my changes but still seeing this error - any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is related to expo-dev-menu, when app installed and opened in first time. Try to run your project in production mode, when expo-dev-menu disabled: `npx expo start --no-dev --minify`